# wordpress custom post div incorrect looping

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wp and little struck with custom post looping within div , here is my code can someone structure me lopping on the div . Only 3 post should be in signle row , but journey_gallery_content only get repeated, journey_gallery_row
not get repeated .

```
<div class="journey_gallery_row">
        <?php
                 $loop=new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'journeypackage',
                                          'sort_column' => 'post_date',
                                          'posts_per_page'=> -1 ,
                                          'order' => 'ASC')
                                    ); 
                 if ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
                     {
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
                            {
                         $loop->the_post();
                         $meta=get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'');
                ?> 
            <div class="journey_gallery_content"> 
                  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
                <div class="journey_package">
                   <div class="journey_package_img">
                        <?php
                    $attachment_id = get_field('package-icon');
                    $size = "et-member-image-small";

                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
                     ?>
                     <img  src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="journey_package_name">
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/journeytitle/enture/"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
                        <p class ="">Date : <?php the_field('package-date'); ?> </p>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
          <?php }
          }?>
          </div>
        </div>   
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `current_post` check

this should work to have each 3 posts put into `the journey_gallery_row` div

```
<?php
                 $loop=new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'journeypackage',
                                          'sort_column' => 'post_date',
                                          'posts_per_page'=> -1 ,
                                          'order' => 'ASC')
                                    ); 
                 if ( $loop->have_posts() ){?>
                    <div class="journey_gallery_row">
                      <?php 
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
                            {
                         $loop->the_post();
                         $meta=get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'');

                ?> 


                            <div class="journey_gallery_content"> 
                  <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
                <div class="journey_package">
                   <div class="journey_package_img">
                        <?php
                    $attachment_id = get_field('package-icon');
                    $size = "et-member-image-small";

                    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
                     ?>
                     <img  src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="journey_package_name">
                        <a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/journeytitle/enture/"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
                        <p class ="">Date : <?php the_field('package-date'); ?> </p>

                    </div>

                </div>
</div>
             <?php if( $loop->current_post % 3 == 2 ) echo '</div>'."\n".'<div class="journey_gallery_row">'; ?>
          <?php }
          }?>
```

Comment: I got the exact result with your answer .

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a custom check in the loop with a variable and increment at the end of loop, that variable will check if the limit equal to the row limit then it will add the close the old row div and add the new row div before the inner content div. may be something like this.

```
  <div class="journey_gallery_row">
    <?php
             $loop=new WP_Query(array('post_type'=>'journeypackage',
                                      'sort_column' => 'post_date',
                                      'posts_per_page'=> -1 ,
                                      'order' => 'ASC')
                                ); 
             if ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
                 {
                 $num = 1;
                    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) 
                        {
                     $loop->the_post();
                     $meta=get_post_meta(get_the_id(),'');
                     if($num%4==0){echo '</div><div class="journey_gallery_row">';}
            ?> 

        <div class="journey_gallery_content"> 
              <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( ); ?>
            <div class="journey_package">
               <div class="journey_package_img">
                    <?php
                $attachment_id = get_field('package-icon');
                $size = "et-member-image-small";

                $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment_id, $size);
                 ?>
                 <img  src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="journey_package_name">
                    <a href="<?php bloginfo('url')?>/journeytitle/enture/"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></a>
                    <p class ="">Date : <?php the_field('package-date'); ?> </p>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
      <?php $num++;
      }
      }?>
      </div>
    </div>   
</div>
```

try something like this.

Comment: Thanks works like charm , have a nice day. 
Additional i have an another issue with the date picker custom field ,
Date : 20160203 , Date is been formatted like this and it does not getting changes . I am using advance custom field, I want the date format as Date : 2016/02/03

Comment: there may be some settings of date formating in the plugin.if it don't have then may be any hook of the plugin.